# ipyleaflet draw_control not handling the "clear all" button

Tags: python, leaflet, ipywidgets

I am using the `draw_control`  function in `ipyleaflet` to draw polygons on a map. I am collecting what I have drawn with the `feature_collection` variable, which works fine. However when I press `clear all` on the map's `bin` button, the `feature_collection` variable does not get emptied - how do I convert the `clear all` button press on the map to clearing my `feature_collection` variable? Currently it duplicates what I drew before, so I have this workflow:

1. Draw two Polygons
2. `feature_collection` contains info about two ploygons
3. Press `clear all` on `bin` button on map.
4. Draw two new Polygons on map
5. `feature_collection` now contains 6(!) entries, duplicating the 1. action twice!

Here is a code to replicate! Basically I don't understand how to collect the `clear_all` action from the `bin` button to clear my `feature_control` variable.

```py
from ipyleaflet import Map, basemaps, basemap_to_tiles, DrawControl, LayersControl, GeoJSON, SearchControl, Marker, FullScreenControl


#Creating empty geojson to collect features drawn on map: 
feature_collection = {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': []}

#Handling items drawn on map: 
def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
    """Do something with the GeoJSON when it's drawn on the map"""    
    feature_collection['features'].append(geo_json)
    
#Generate Basemap: 
satellite = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.Esri.WorldImagery)
osmap = basemap_to_tiles(basemaps.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
mymap = Map(layers=(osmap, satellite), center=(55,0), zoom=5,scroll_wheel_zoom=True)

#Generate controls on map:
center=[55,0] #where to start on map: middle of UK
marker = Marker(location=center, draggable=False)

#Draw shapes on map: 
dc = DrawControl(
    marker={'shapeOptions': {'color': '#0000FF'}},
    rectangle={'shapeOptions': {'color': '#0000FF'}},
    circlemarker={}
)

dc.on_draw(handle_draw) #call function what to do with objects drawn on maps

#Add all controls to the actual map: 
mymap.add_control(dc) #add 

#Generate GEOJSON which could contain data to be displayed on map: 
geo_json = GeoJSON(data={},style={},hover_style={})
                   
mymap.add_layer(geo_json) #add to map object

mymap
```

Answer (score 0):

In `handle_draw` method you have more that just the `geo_json` feature, you also have an `action` parameter that help you handle what is going on in your `DrawingControl`.

On clear the `action` will be `deleted`.

So to adapt your code, you can do the following:

```py
#Handling items drawn on map: 
def handle_draw(self, action, geo_json):
    """Do something with the GeoJSON when it's drawn on the map""" 

    if action in ['created', 'edited']:
        feature_collection['features'].append(geo_json)

    elif action == 'deleted':
        feature_collection['features'].remove(geo_json)

    return
```

Note that as 'edited' is not giving any information about the original shape, you can't know which one to modify